# Javascript createElement vs. getElementById

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to use tile to identify the newly created div here:

```
var tile = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById('tileBlock').appendChild(tile);
var tileName = 'tile' + numbersToLetters(tileX) + numbersToLetters(tileY);
tile.setAttribute('id', tileName);
tile = blah blah blah...
```

Or do I need to reattach tile?

```
var tile = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById('tileBlock').appendChild(tile);
var tileName = 'tile' + numbersToLetters(tileX) + numbersToLetters(tileY);
tile.setAttribute('id', tileName);
tile = document.getElementById(tileName);
tile = blah blah blah...
```

Comment: Yes, it's totally safe.

Comment: Each DOM element is unique instance, which exists during the lifetime of the page (until reload that is). The characteristics of the element itself might change (ID, class names, event handlers), but the instance doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to re-fetch the element, and you don't really need to use `.setAttribute()`:

```
tile.id = tileName;
```

Changing the "id" property does not "break" your reference to the element. The value of the variable "tile" remains unchanged, in other words.